# How to combine many 'if' statements into one?

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, optimization

I'm triyng to combine my validation if-statements, but it stops working.

```
function setPlaceHolderModal(input, text) {
    input.value = '';
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', text + '!');
}
```

```
function validation(inputs) {
    const [inputText, inputNumber] = inputs;
    const matchedNumb = inputText.value.match(/\d+/g)
       for (let el of inputs) {
            if (el.value === '') {
                el.setAttribute('placeholder', 'please fill the field!');
            }
            if (inputText.value.length > 13) {
                setPlaceHolderModal(inputText, 'please fill title shorter');
            }
            if (matchedNumb != null) {
                setPlaceHolderModal(inputText, 'can not use numbers')
            }
            if (/[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/.test(inputText.value)) {
                setPlaceHolderModal(inputText, 'can not use this characters');

            }
            if (inputNumber.value.length > 5) {
                setPlaceHolderModal(inputNumber, 'please fill price shorter')
            }
        }        
    }
```

I tried to put these if statements into one big if-statement but it stops working

Comment: all this is useless, HTML5 forms offer automatic validation mechanisms for this kind of thing with customizable messages (by bubbles) which allow not to distort the entries

Comment: [A link to the relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got a different error for every invalid condition, you probably can't really shorten this. But if you're alright with having just 1 error message, you could do:

```js
// Outer loop

if (
  el.value === '' || inputText.value.length > 13 || matchedNumb != null
  || /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/.test(inputText.value)
  || inputNumber.value.length > 5
) {
  // Display a generic error
}
// Closing curly brackets for the loop and function
```